# Database Table As Data Source Into Open Telemetry

Tags: oracle, open-telemetry

It it possible to have OpenTelmentry consume table data, oracle in this case, so it is sent to our Observabilty application? At this point the only way I can come up with is to have a job that writes table data to a file that OpenTelmentry can read.